# Android fragments popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, behavior

I have the following issue and I'm no quite sure whether it is a bug or misunderstanding by me.

I have a single activity, `Fragment A` *(attached to activity's onCreate Method)* and `Fragment B` *(not attached to activity during its creation)*. On button click, `Fragment A` is replaced with `Fragment B` with transition. So far so good.

On `Fragment B` there is button which invokes `fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()`. *If I press this button and turn the screen off at the same time (during fragment transition)* then, **when the screen is back on, the two fragments are visible (fragment B should have been destroyed, but it is not)**.

This problem starts with support lib `27.1.0+`. Prior to that, the fragments were replaced correctly during Back stack navigation. Have in mind that I'm using fragments from support library.

I read behavior changes but I could not manage to link some of it to my issue.

Does anybody knows some work around or has more information about it?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Problem exists only on devices up to Android 6. On Android 7+ everything is alright.

Answer (score 0):

fragmentManager.beginTrasaction().replace().addToBackStack() - do it for FragmentA in onCreate and do it on click for FragmentB. And try popBackStack(). I think you forgot addToBackStack FragmentA.

Comment: Thank for the tip, but addToBackStack() is not forgotten.